# Configure the DBContext Asyncronously to avoid GetAwaiter().GetResult() in TokenAcquisition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Environment:

- net6.0
- EFCore 6
- Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.23

Using `ITokenAcquisition` from Microsoft.Identity.Web, I'm able to get a token for the User / ManagedIdentity successfully, but the methods are async so I must `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in order to access the token.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAuthenticationResultForUserAsync(LocalConstants.dbScopes).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(LocalConstants.AzureDbConnection);
        connection.AccessToken = token.AccessToken;
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection,
            providerOptions => { providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(); })
            .EnableDetailedErrors();
    }
}
```

Questions:

- Is there a way to make the `OnConfiguring` method asynchronous?
- When I have tried, it fails to create a `DbContext`?

Comment: `OnConfiguring` does not have an async version.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thank you. Should I acquire a token in another way? Does this matter in this case? I often see GetAwaiter discouraged / identified as bad code.

Comment: `await` is the preferred way over `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` if you **can** use `async`. If you can't then `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is the preferred way over `.Result`

Comment: Not needed  just use the new connection string options

Comment: OnConfiguring is bad place to retrieve something from database. It is called only ONCE per DbContext type.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm not retrieving anything from the database in the OnCofiguring method above, am I?

Comment: @ErikEJ I still require a token for the connection in the application to access the database on behalf of the logged in user in Azure. How would I do tha twith just the connection string?

Comment: Check the [following approach](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11928#issuecomment-699537732). Also check [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/pull/730)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv excellent, that did it.  It was pretty straightforward to implement as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.1 or later:

```
// For system-assigned managed identity
string ConnectionString1 = @"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity; Database=testdb";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1)) {
    conn.Open();
}
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-managed-identity-authentication

Comment: I'm sorry, I see that I included Managed Identity in my question and really should not have. I do use this for the token cache and it is perfect there. Unfortunately I need to acquire the token on behalf of the user and pass it to the connection.

Default won't work because it might use the ManagedIdentity instead of the user.